# Available but Not Available functions on OperationQueue in Swift

Tags: swift, combine, operationqueue

MacOS Swift Project, but would for iOS.  I am targeting 10.14

I have an OperationQueue.  I want to schedule an operation to run later.  Easy enough...

```
func schedule(after date: OperationQueue.SchedulerTimeType, interval: OperationQueue.SchedulerTimeType.Stride, tolerance: OperationQueue.SchedulerTimeType.Stride, options: OperationQueue.SchedulerOptions?, _ action: @escaping () -> Void) -> Cancellable
```

Available 10.9

```
        operQ.schedule(after: .init(restartDate), interval: .zero, tolerance: .zero, options: nil){self.restart("")}
```

I get the error `'schedule(after:interval:tolerance:options:_:)' is only available in macOS 10.15 or newer`

Which I tracked down to combine, which seems to be masking the default implementation.

[image: Screen Shot of the Xcode doc]

Comment: where do you see 10.9? I see 10.15: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue/3329364-schedule